# How to predict class of a instance in Waffles c++ API

Tags: c++, machine-learning, classification

my name is titiri and happy that I found waffle library to classification. I think waffle is a good library for machine learning algorithms.
I have a question about waffle library.

After training a model, I want print a prediction, for a instance:

my code is:

```
GMatrix Instance(1,8);//instance have 8 real attribute and 
double out;// value in attribute 'class' is nomial 
Instance[0][0]=6;
Instance[0][1]=148;
Instance[0][2]=72;
Instance[0][3]=35;
Instance[0][4]=0;
Instance[0][5]=33.6;
Instance[0][6]=0.62;
Instance[0][7]=50;
modell->predict(Instance[0],&out);
cout<<&out;
```

This code do not work true and does not print anything.
Please help me!
What do  I need to predict class of a instance , then print its class,
have a good performance 'predict' method for classify a instance?
Or is there a better method for this work ?

thanks,
Be happy and win

Comment: The statement `cout<<&out;` outputs the _address_ of the variable `out`.

Comment: How about `cout << out << endl;`?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason your code does not print anything is because you forgot the `endl`. (This is what [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) mentioned in his comment.)

If you are using Visual Studio, you may want to add a breakpoint at the end of your code (maybe on the return statement) because in certain modes it can close your application before you get to see the output, which can make it seem as if nothing happened.

## Example

What follows is a full example that works fine for me. It includes your instance. It loads a K-nearest neighbors learner from `2blobs_knn.json` and then evaluates your instance on it. You can replace that file name with the name of any trained supervised model generated by the waffles tools.

With the model I used, the program prints "1" and exits.

If you want to use the exact model that I tested my code with (in case your method of constructing your learner is the problem) see the section after the example code.

```
#include <GClasses/GMatrix.h>
#include <GClasses/GHolders.h>
#include <GClasses/GRand.h>
#include <GClasses/GLearner.h>
#include <GClasses/GDom.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace GClasses;
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //Load my trained learner from a file named 2blobs_knn.json and put
  //it in hModel which is a shared-pointer class.
  GLearnerLoader ll(GRand::global());
  GDom dom;
  dom.loadJson("2blobs_knn.json");
  Holder<GSupervisedLearner> hModel(ll.loadSupervisedLearner(dom.root()));
  assert(hModel.get() != NULL);


  //Here is your code
  GMatrix Instance(1,8);// Instance has 8 real attributes and one row
  double out;           // The value in attribute 'class' is nominal 
  Instance[0][0]=6;
  Instance[0][1]=148;
  Instance[0][2]=72;
  Instance[0][3]=35;
  Instance[0][4]=0;
  Instance[0][5]=33.6;
  Instance[0][6]=0.62;
  Instance[0][7]=50;

  hModel.get()->predict(Instance[0],&out);
  cout << out << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## How the learner I used in the example was constructed

To get the learner, I used Matlab ([Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) is the free imitator) to generate a CSV file in which class 0 was an 8-dimensional spherical unit Gaussian centered at (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) and class 1 had the same distribution but centered at (2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

```
m=[[randn(200,8);randn(200,8)+2], [repmat(0,200,1);repmat(1,200,1)]];
csvwrite('2blobs.csv',m)
```

Then, I took that CSV, converted it to ARFF using

```
waffles_transform import 2blobs.csv > 2blobs.arff
```

Next, I changed the last attribute from `@ATTRIBUTE attr8        real` to
`@ATTRIBUTE class        {0,1}` in a text editor so it would be nominal.

Finally, I trained the model with

```
waffles_learn train 2blobs.arff knn -neighbors 10 > 2blobs_knn.json
```

Comment: No, you don't want to add `system("Pause")` to your code, regardless of compiler/IDE. Visual Studio will route stdout to its output window, which lives past the end of the application, making that entirely unnecessary.

Comment: It depends on the version of Visual Studio. In 2008 (last time I used VS) it used to send output to the terminal and close the terminal if you executed in debug mode (F5) rather than in release mode (CTRL-F5). See, the [Microsoft Q&A](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/636a5fe5-06e8-4eaa-b88b-3d16921f161d), for example. (Incidentally, the MS Q&A looks suspiciously like StackOverflow)

Comment: Even if you're in attached debugging mode, a breakpoint at the end of `main` is still simpler (doesn't have to be removed later) and works just as well.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit my answer to suggest a breakpoint instead of `system("Pause");`

Comment: That is not something I can answer fully in a comment. Quickly, you need to use the serialize function in the trained model to save it to a DOM and then GDOM::saveJson to write it out. If you need any more detail ask another question.

Comment: Also, you ought to accept this answer if you like it (click the check-mark under the number of votes at the top of the answer). It will give both you and I reputation points.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not 15 reputation

Comment: thank you Eponymous.I save my trained model with same way.but doc.saveJson('A:/home') take a long time!!!!(too much time)